# how can select multiple class in simple way with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, class

I created 7 class for 7 div and i want to select them easily with short code

HTML code:

```
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon1"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon2"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon3"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon4"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon5"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon6"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon7"></div>
```

in jQuery

```
$("[select all classes]").click(function(){
   //$(this) do something
})
```

EDIT:

please don't answer me like that

```
$('.icon1, .icon2, .icon3, .icon4, .icon5, .icon6, .icon7').click(function() {

})
```

because i have 25 icons that i wanna do something and it's not a good code for do something

how can i select them easily?

Comment: why don't you assign another class to all those elemnts like `<div height="38" width="38" class="icon1 icon"></div>` then just `$('.icon')`

Comment: no no no, i wanna create separate events for any of icons

Comment: If you want seperate events, then you wouldn't want to select them all at once anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all elements with their class name starts with `icon`:

```js
var icon = $("[class^=icon]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon1"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon2"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon3"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon4"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon5"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon6"></div>
<div height="38" width="38" class="icon7"></div>
```

References:

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: thank you but it just write [object object] and can't return the icon class name

Comment: Returns an array of objects. What is your issue?

Comment: i haven't problem to use your code with divs but it will give me errors when i use it for <td></td> tag of table how can i select them too?

Comment: There should not be a problem with `td` if they have same classes.

Comment: wow, it working thank you, i learned it as well from you, thanks again

Comment: Glad that I helped you.